# Do I have to specify both stage flags to ensure the proper memory invalidation?

Tags: vulkan

If I issue a transfer command, and then want to read that data from the shaders (both vertex and fragment), I'd do like this:

```
cmd_buffer->issueTransferCommand();
PIPELINE BARRIER
srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_WRITE_BIT; /* flush the transfer writes */
dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT;
dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_READ_BIT; /* invalidate the caches from the point of view of the vertex shader */
```

Do I have specify the invalidation of the caches for the fragment shader stage as well?

Comment: You should not think of these things in terms of implementation details. You're not "specifying the invalidation of the caches". You're providing a memory dependency between a producer and a consumer; how that gets implemented in hardware is not your concern. The destination stage mask says which stages consume the data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all pipeline stages must be explicitly included for the purposes of *memory dependencies*.

Comment: If I transferred vertices, then I'd do srcStageMask = VK_STAGE_TRANSFER and dstStageMask = VK_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT,  but you're saying that's not good enough for the cache invalidation, VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ? I'd have to do VK_STAGE_VERTEX_INPUT | VK_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER | VK_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER ? It seems rather inconvenient.

Comment: @Zebrafish Convenience is irrelevant at low level. Only explicitness, predictability, and simplicity is relevant. If you are doing something weird, that's fine. All you need to do is tell the driver. Why keep the driver guessing if you can **simply** tell it what you are doing and what are your intentions? You read vertex data in fragment shader? Odd. But who are we to judge. Just **simply** explicitly tell the driver you are reading vertex data in fragment shader and all is well. Such code will be clearer to the driver as well as anyone reading it after you.

Comment: "You read vertex data in fragment shader?" No, actually I issue a command to transfer the vertices to the vertex buffer and then another transfer directly after it (not synchronised with each other) to transfer the uniforms/SSBOs, then there needs to be a barrier before the draw commands. Since the first transfer is sending vertices then the barrier dstStageMask needs to start at vertex input because it's reading the vertices. The vertex and fragment shaders read the uniforms/SSBOs (the second transfer), so I need to explicity include vertex and fragment shader stages or'd together?

Comment: @Zebrafish Memory is memory. Doesn't matter what is in the memory. If you use "it" in vertex and fragment shader both, then you tell the driver you are using it in vertex and fragment shader with appropriate stage and access masks.

Comment: Yes, I understand the point of specifying which stages use it, but the system works so that any dst stage mask includes "logically earlier pipeline stages", so you don't specify like 4 stages for the execution dependency, but I suppose you have to for the purposes of memory visibility/availability. I also suppose if you change up the pipeline a little, so let's say you add a geometry shader between the vertex and fragment shader, then another stage mask would need to be or'd with the existing ones.

Comment: @Zebrafish dst stage includes logically-**later** pipeline stages. Src includes logically-earlier. Definition of barrier is basically "do all of this before you do any of that". So everything before "this" is implied. And everything after "that" is implied in the dependency. Because well, if you have not executed any vertex shaders, then it implies no fragment shaders were executed neither.